# PHPWord configuration issue

Tags: php, html, ms-word, doc

I am having problem running script of PHPWord.

I am trying to run sample example. Text.php after running it doesn't show anything. I checked it loads class successfully. [Documentation](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation).

I would like to able to run script anyone has this problem.

Comment: what error you are getting? Check system requirements and PHPWord.php settings.

Comment: Doesn't show anything on screen? or in helloWorld.docx?

Comment: No anything!!! Have you tried to do it. I tried to follow what exactly they have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did -

1. Downloaded `PHPWord_0.6.2_Beta.zip` from [Download link.](http://phpword.codeplex.com/releases/view/49543)
2. Extracted the zip under htdocs/core/phpword.
3. Created `swap.php` and pasted the whole code what was mentioned at [Link](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation)
4. Commented, this is it was showing error.

> ```
> //$myTextElement->setBold();
> //$myTextElement->setName('Verdana');
> //$myTextElement->setSize(22);
> ```

Now i run swap.php file and `helloWorld.docx` successfully created. You can flag a message if you want in that file. Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: No, nothing so far, I have enabled error in php even in script. it runs but no result

Comment: Can it be because of php configuration

Comment: helloWorld.docx file is not created ??? check system requirement, already mentioned at the site link

Comment: I installed necessary pack. but how about If i am going to run it linux based server.